# Change a column value within a dataframe based on multi-index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe that contains traffic incidences (predictable and non-predictable incidences). I want to delete predictable incidences after changing the value of predictable column to `1` for those non-predictable incidences that has a predictable incidence at a concrete day and city

```py
df['predictable'] = 0 #initialising predictable column to 0
df['startDate_dupli'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startDate']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
predictable_incidences = df[df['incidenceType'].isin(['Event', 'Labour'])] #filtering predictable incidences from original dataframe
df.set_index(['cityTown', 'startDate_dupli'], inplace=True)
predictable_incidences['startDate_dupli'] = pd.to_datetime(predictable_incidences['startDate']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
zipped_list = list(zip(predictable_incidences['cityTown'].to_list(), predictable_incidences['startDate_dupli'].to_list()))
print(zipped_list) #Contains a mapping of predictable incidences city/date [('Madrid', '2020-01-02'), ('Barcelona', '2021-04-03'),...]
df.loc[zipped_list, 'predictable'] = 1 #setting predictable to 1 for those matches with non-predictable incidences
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
final_df = df[~df['incidenceType'].isin(['Event', 'Labour'])] #filtering to obtain non-predictable incidences
print(final_df)
```

The code that I provided above, sets every combination of city/Date within `zipped_list` to `1`, so that if the content of zipped_list is equal to the following:

```py
zipped_list = [('Madrid', '2020-01-02'), ('Barcelona', '2021-04-03')]
```

It changes predictable flag to `1` in 4 different rows, like so:

| cityTown | startDate | predictable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Madrid | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| Barcelona | 2021-04-03 | 1 |
| Madrid | 2021-04-03 | 1 |
| Barcelona | 2020-01-02 | 1 |

When it should only change the following rows(2):

| cityTown | startDate | predictable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Madrid | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| Barcelona | 2021-04-03 | 1 |
| Madrid | 2021-04-03 | 0 |
| Barcelona | 2020-01-02 | 0 |

If you need any further explanation about some of the aspects mentioned above or you have any other alternative that can make it easier to accomplish the final result, please don't hold back and let me know.

Thank you very much
Any help is very welcome

Comment: if you've copied and pasted your code from elsewhere, you have a backtick in your second last line where you should have a single quote 
`final_df = df[~df['incidenceType\`]`

Comment: I didn't copy, I just made a typo right there. Fixed, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'predictable': {('Madrid', pd.Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00')): 0,
                        ('Barcelona', pd.Timestamp('2021-04-03 00:00:00')): 0,
                        ('Madrid', pd.Timestamp('2021-04-03 00:00:00')): 0,
                        ('Barcelona', pd.Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00')): 0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename_axis(index=['cityTown', 'startDate'])
print(df)

# Output
                      predictable
cityTown  startDate              
Madrid    2020-01-02            0
Barcelona 2021-04-03            0
Madrid    2021-04-03            0
Barcelona 2020-01-02            0
```

Your code should work:

```
zipped_list = [('Madrid', '2020-01-02'), ('Barcelona', '2021-04-03')]
df.loc[zipped_list, 'predictable'] = 1
print(df)

# Output
                      predictable
cityTown  startDate              
Madrid    2020-01-02            1
Barcelona 2021-04-03            1
Madrid    2021-04-03            0
Barcelona 2020-01-02            0
```

Comment: Knowing that it should work I will check in depth the structure of the dataframe, multi-index, columns and so on. Hopefully I manage to find the hassle, it's driving me crazy...

Comment: I have discovered one thing, which may be causing some problems down the road. There are repeated multi-indexes, since in the dataframe there are accidents that occur on the same day and in the same city. I feel like I should remove repeated ones in order to prevent unexpected behaviours.